# How do I map return types into a tuple?

Tags: typescript

I have an array of instances where execute returns a type, here are for example 2 classe whose instances are in the array:

```
class ClassBase<TReturn>
{
   execute (): TReturn
}

class ReturnsString extends ClassBase<string>
{
   execute () : string
}

class ReturnsNumber extends ClassBase<number>
{
   execute () : number
}

const items:[ReturnsString,ReturnsNumber] = [new ReturnsString(), new ReturnsNumber()];
```

inside a method i will call execute in a loop for each item in tuple.

How to declare a method that

- accepts items - items could be of any length and can contain various types, eg. could be [ReturnString] or [ReturnString,ReturnString,ReturnString,ReturnNumber,....]
- returns type of the returning type tuple [string,string,string,number]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use mapped types to map over a tuple and extract the return type for each tuple item:

```
type ReturnsOfClassBase<T extends Record<number, ClassBase<any>>> = {
  -readonly [P in keyof T] : T[P] extends ClassBase<infer R> ? R: never
}
function getReturns<T extends readonly ClassBase<any>[]>(p: T): ReturnsOfClassBase<T> {
  const result = []
  for(let r of p) {
    result.push(r.execute());
  }

  return result as any
}

let r = getReturns(items)
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgwq9AhNApgDwAqASgRAK5QB2AfAFADejC7okM8CBAHgVhUIBBAAoAlAC4E5SjVqMAvo0Yo0GCtTpgAytACWtAOa8+I2gBMM2DfjDEuR401bszg4aMkIZTkwjMCFDydAgAROEIKipqOJqhtGAAclQAtiAEUGYW1ljx9sS06ZlQrmzs-J4i4hK+CMUZWYHBiQgADNHKqrAA9kmIBiJpGAC8CADatAQA7ghaCnqGJpIANA2z84kpJVmSALoIaEj9kADcqowQAJ4ADqILOgDyAGa2eISkOQRWCX1QliIjVK63eYEKRGAtGu9FhCHGbgQAFoQsBLP1kNdJgAFBBGBAAawI116L1khxkJAm2MO-FyNgKnyML2aZHoCAA-PMZNMAG5ZbovKi0eAGfoIYyUR5JL50n55VHo2iY-J2T5QmETfb0MS3SnSLbaJKvMEQkjsxF9AatMBUZCIcZaiovXpQMTISjBBCkhC3OqI9ghW32gB0tyoYAAFmIoCGqkIRJIJBd2LFA20g3bEMcNd1GB7ENlxpKINKwGIhgQRhIgA)

Comment: I tried this solution, but it still returns a tuple of union. What the question wants is to return a tuple type matching the length and order of the input tuple.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai If you check the playground link, you'll see that `r` is `[string, number]` so it does work for the given example. If something is not working for you ask another question and I can have a look

Comment: I did check, and I ran my own example. But I noticed your one has `as const` for the `items`. Without that, it goes back to array of union.

Comment: What is the `as const` doing? And it's not mentioned in your answer.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai This answer assumes that the parameter ( in this case `items` ) is already a tuple. If you want `T` to be inferred as a tuple when you call the function with `getReturns( [new ReturnsString(), new ReturnsNumber()])`, you can use `T extends (readonly [ClassBase<any>] | readonly ClassBase<any>[])` as a constraint instead.

Comment: So the reason is that if just do `const items = [...];`, TS infers it to be an array, and when it's an array, the mapped type becomes a tuple/array of union. So the `as const` is a way of forcing TS to recognise it as a tuple.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Yes. That is right, if the input is an array of union, the output will be an array. If it is a tuple the output is a tuple. By default TS infers arrays not tuples, `as const` makes it infer a readonly tuple

Answer (score 1):

I recently implemented a similar types:

```js
type TransformTuple<Tuple extends (() => any)[], Returns extends any[] = []> =
  Tuple extends [() => any, ...infer More] ?
    More extends (() => any)[] ?
      TransformTuple<More, [...Returns, ReturnType<Tuple[0]>]>
      : never
    : Returns

type Test = TransformTuple<[() => 1, () => "2"]>
/*
type Test = [1, "2"]
*/

//NOTE Only tuples are supported

//If use normal array like this:
type Test2 = TransformTuple<Array<() => "never">>
/*
//You only get an empty array
type Test2 = []
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

nice question! It made me think a lot and use many advanced TS typing features, but I guess that this makes what you are looking for:

```
abstract class ClassBase<TReturn = any>
{
   abstract execute (): TReturn
}

type FlattenIfArray<T> = T extends (infer R)[] ? R : T
type ExtendsOf<T> = T extends ClassBase<infer R> ? R : T
type ExecuteArrayReturn<T> = ExtendsOf<FlattenIfArray<T>>

function example<T extends ClassBase<ExecuteArrayReturn<T>>[]>(items: T): ExecuteArrayReturn<T> {
    return items.map(item => item.execute()) as any
}

class ReturnsString extends ClassBase<string>
{
   execute () : string {return 'a'}
}

class ReturnsNumber extends ClassBase<number>
{
   execute () : number {return 1}
}

const items:[ReturnsString,ReturnsNumber] = [new ReturnsString(), new ReturnsNumber()];

const result = example(items);
```

I needed to create some types to extract the `execute` function return value from instances of the `ClassBase` heirs. `FlattenIfArray` gets the type of the array items, `ExtendsOf` get the type of the generic type that has been set to `T` and `ExecuteArrayReturn` join both of them.

When you implement your real function, don't forget about the `as any` on the function `return`. Otherwise, TS will think that you want to return an array of the provided items types union, for example: `(string | number)[]`.

Comment: But this solution returns an array of a union type. The request was explicitly for a tuple. And it can be done, see my answer :)